# SwiftUI: Lauch new view from a slider menu that is not covered by previous view

Tags: view, swiftui, hamburger-menu

I am completely new to SwiftUI so I hope this is not a stupid question. In my project I have a home view (a map) and a Menu button in the top right corner. Upon clicking that button my menu is gonna slide in from the left. For each of the menu items I want to use NavigationLink to jump to the next detail views.

**Now here is the problem:** When I click on the menu items (eg. Payments) I get the view but my button and my map are still on top of that view and I cant get rid of it, or at least I dont know how.. :(.
I saw a few similar questions but I couldnt make it work for my case.

This is my view when the menu view is true
[image: This is my view when the menu view is true]

This is my problem view. When I click on eg. Payments I cant get rid of the Map and the button in that view
[image: This is my problem view. When I click on eg. Payments I cant get rid of the Map and the button in that view]

This is my HomeView (The Map and the button)code:

```
 import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    @State var showMenu = false


var body: some View {
        let drag = DragGesture()
            .onEnded {
                if $0.translation.width < -100 {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.showMenu = false
                    }
                }
            }
        return GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                if self.showMenu {
                SlideInMenuView()
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width/1)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                }

                HomeSupportView()
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .scaleEffect(self.showMenu ? 0.8 : 1)
                    .offset(x: self.showMenu ? 150 : 0, y : self.showMenu ? 50 : 0)
                    .disabled(self.showMenu ? true : false)

                MenuButton(showMenu: self.$showMenu)

            }
            .gesture(drag)
        }
    }
}


struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}

struct MenuButton: View {
    @Binding var showMenu: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation {
                self.showMenu.toggle()
            }
        }){
            Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 60)
                .background(Color.black)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .opacity(0.8)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(self.showMenu ? 90 : 0))
                .scaleEffect(self.showMenu ? 1.2 : 1)
        }
        .padding(.top, -380)
    }
}
```

This is my menu view code with my try of making the NavigationLink work. I tried it on the "Payments" HStack in multiple versions but I just cant make it work

```
import SwiftUI

struct SlideInMenuView: View {
    @State private var showingPaymentDetails = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {

            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "person")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .imageScale(.large)
                Text("Profile")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .font(.headline)
            }
            .padding(.top, 150.0)
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "person.2.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .imageScale(.large)
                Text("Matches")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .font(.headline)
            }
            .padding(.top, 30)
            NavigationLink(destination:
                PaymentDetailsView())
            {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "creditcard")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                    Text("Payments")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .font(.headline)
                }
                .padding(.top, 30)
            }

            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "hammer")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .imageScale(.large)
                Text("Settings")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .font(.headline)
            }
            .padding(.top, 30)
            Spacer()

        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .background(Color(red: 32/255, green: 32/255, blue: 32/255))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

    }
    }
}

struct SlideInMenuView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SlideInMenuView()
    }
}
```

If anyone knows how to help me out here...
Thank you very much in advance guys.
**Stay healthy.**

Cheers,
LeBob

[@Chris: This is how I want it to be. I put in 4 consecutive screenshots with the respective clicks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHk2v.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***** UPDATED ANSWER *****

thank you for your clarifying pictures

try this:

```
import SwiftUI

class Global : ObservableObject {

    @Published var showMenu = true
    @Published var showMenuButton = true

}

struct PaymentDetailsView : View {

    @EnvironmentObject var global : Global

    var body: some View {
        Text("payment")
            .onAppear() {
                withAnimation() {
                    self.global.showMenuButton = false
                }
        }
        .onDisappear() {
            withAnimation() {
                self.global.showMenuButton = true
            }
        }
    }
}

struct HomeSupportView : View  {

    @EnvironmentObject var global : Global

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle().fill(Color.blue)
            Text("home")
        }
    }
}



struct SlideInMenuView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var global : Global

    @State private var showingPaymentDetails = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                    Text("Profile")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .font(.headline)
                }
                .padding(.top, 150.0)
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "person.2.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                    Text("Matches")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .font(.headline)
                }
                .padding(.top, 30)
                NavigationLink(destination:
                    PaymentDetailsView().environmentObject(self.global))
                {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "creditcard")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .imageScale(.large)
                        Text("Payments")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .font(.headline)
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 30)
                }

                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "hammer")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                    Text("Settings")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .font(.headline)
                }
                .padding(.top, 30)
                Spacer()

            }
            .padding()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .background(Color(red: 32/255, green: 32/255, blue: 32/255))
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

        }
    }
}

struct SlideInMenuView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SlideInMenuView().environmentObject(Global())
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var global : Global

    var body: some View {
        let drag = DragGesture()
            .onEnded {
                if $0.translation.width < -100 {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.global.showMenu = false
                    }
                }
        }
        return GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                if self.global.showMenu {
                    SlideInMenuView()
                        .environmentObject(self.global)
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width/1)
                        .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                        .zIndex(3)
                }

                HomeSupportView()
                    .environmentObject(self.global)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .scaleEffect(self.global.showMenu ? 0.8 : 1)
                    .offset(x: self.global.showMenu ? 150 : 0, y : self.global.showMenu ? 50 : 0)
                    .disabled(self.global.showMenu ? true : false)
                    .zIndex((2))

                MenuButton().environmentObject(self.global)
                    .zIndex(4)
            }
            .gesture(drag)
        }
    }
}


struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(Global())
    }
}

struct MenuButton: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var global: Global

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation {
                self.global.showMenu.toggle()
            }
        }){
            if self.global.showMenuButton {
                Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 60)
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .opacity(0.8)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(self.global.showMenu ? 90 : 0))
                    .scaleEffect(self.global.showMenu ? 1.2 : 1)
            } else {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, -380)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Chris for your time and help, I appreciate it. I think it got me closer to it. But I want to stick to the view design from the first picture once I open the menu. Once I click on one of the menu items I want to see that on the full screen. So basically like in the second picture but without the map and the menu button being visable. from that detail view when I click on Back in the top left I want to be back at the view from picture 1.

Comment: Do you know what I mean? Sorry its my second language :)

Comment: Hey Chris, I put in 4 consecutive screenshots in my original post. Thanks, man.

Comment: Ahhh sorry, I just saw your updated post. I will check that right away...

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI has a zIndex() modifier that you can use to order the views.
This could help in your situation.